# How to stop Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

The only answer on this question I saw - go start another copy on the different port.
[Switching from one Meteor workspace to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115931/switching-from-one-meteor-workspace-to-another)
Okay, I see that I can run another one on the different port, BUT how to stop the first one?

Comment: Cast `Holy` *(sorry, couldn't resist.)*

Comment: When I work on 1 project and want to start working on another. I have 2 choices - reboot or start it on another port. Why it is no option to stop Meteor?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I use this command:

```
kill -9 `ps ax | grep node | grep meteor | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Or, I run this if I'm on my local machine to kill remote processes:

```
ssh [user]@[server] <<'ENDSSH'
kill -9 `ps ax | grep node | grep meteor | awk '{print $1}'`
exit
ENDSSH
```

Comment: OSX is not my case. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Does it kill the database? After this command on Ubuntu I still have one Meteor process running :/

Comment: But how do I kill production meteor bundle? It seems to be running with some kind of deamon. If I use this command it's immediatelly going to come up again with a new PID.

Answer (score 32):

On OSX, go back to the term you opened to start meteor, and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to quit the process.

Answer (score 9):

if Meteor is running on :3000 port:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000 -t);
```

Comment: I would not use -9 because that does not give meteor a chance to clean up.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Fernando's response, if you're on OSX you can quit the processes `node` and `mongod` using Activity Monitor.

quitting `node` will stop the server. The database will still be running and accepting incoming connections, so quitting `mongod` will turn off the database.

Answer (score 4):

Enter command "Ctrl + C" on the terminal where the meteor process is running. This is the easiest way to kill the process in both Mac and Ubuntu. Not sure of Windows though.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 3):

In my case (Ubuntu 11.10) I open the System Monitor and kill manually the `node` and `mongod` processes.

Of course you can use also the terminal and kill these processes knowing their PID's.

Answer (score 2):

An edit to John Devor's (accepted) answer: if you're editing your code with Atom, his command may kill the editor instances:

```
$ ps ax | grep node | grep meteor
19312 pts/2    Sl+    0:16 /home/teo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.e4elpj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node /home/teo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.e4elpj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js
19541 pts/2    Sl+    0:02 /home/teo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.e4elpj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node /home/teo/meteor/beari/dist/.meteor/local/build/main.js
24438 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/share/atom/atom --no-deprecation /home/teo/.atom/packages/linter-jshint/node_modules/jshint/bin/jshint --reporter /home/teo/.atom/packages/linter-jshint/node_modules/jshint-json/json.js --filename /home/teo/meteor/beari/beari.js -
```

Better to use a command like:

```
kill -9 `ps ax | grep node | grep meteor | grep -v atom | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are looking at the terminal with the unwanted meteor running just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to turn off meteor.

To run more applications side by side run on a different port with the `--port` option

Comment: Shouldn't this be the correct answer? Start a meteor process in a terminal with $ meteor and end it with ctrl+c (like any other terminal process)

Comment: In my case there was no active terminal to end the process.  Via some quirk of my IDE and OS Meteor was still running and there was no terminal that I could end it with ctrl+c.  John Devor's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

use `sudo killall -9 node` command. it will kill all the rprocess.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `kill -9` kills meteor immediately, which is not a good idea. It's an emergency feature and should be applied only when regular `kill` (no signal specified) fails, as it prevents processes from running shutdown procedures.

Answer (score 1):

the default port is 3000.If you want to run it in a different port use below
meteor run --port 3030

run this in two command prompt.If you want to stop use ctrl+c in necessary command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Enter command "Ctrl + C" on the terminal where you want to stop process is running. This is the easiest way to kill the process in both Mac and Ubuntu and Windows.And you can use "meteor run --port portnumber" to run the two or more projects at the same time

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple in my case, I always have two terminal tabs open, one for launching Meteor/stopping it and the other terminal for working the commands. So to stop it I just do the universal `control+c` to stop the working process.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, I used: `$ sudo killall -9 node` (this kills all running node jobs)