# How do I stop all the running meteor servers

Tags: meteor

I know I can switch the port meteor is running on for a new project, but how do I quit the other ports that are running. I have closed the terminal windows they were running in so I cant do crtl + c

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Usually when you close the terminal windows, particularly on OS-X the node child process would also be terminated. Are you sure its meteor using up the port numbers? You could check my running Activity Monitor and looking for node and mongod processes and stopping them too

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop Meteor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238382/how-to-stop-meteor)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the Activity Monitor

`Applications/Utilities/Application Monitor.app`

Select any processes called `node` and click `Quit Process`