# Meteor app not showing up/Can't kill process either (on VPS)

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, meteor

So this question is somewhat twofold.  I followed the instructions to create a meteor project on my Ubuntu VPS.  I navigated to mysite.com:3000 and it did not show up.  I tried to kill the process and restart (killed node on port 3000) and after issuing 'meteor' command to run a new process, I got an error stating that an instance of Meteor was already running on that port.  How do I fix these problems?

Comment: are you sure you need to specify the port if you're trying to access it by the full domain name?

Comment: oh, btw, you may need to kill mongod in addition to node to shut it down http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238382/how-to-stop-meteor