# Stop meteor through a shell command

Tags: macos, shell, meteor

Thanks to some help I just now got on this site, I know how to start up my meteor app (start the meteor server running) with a shell script that I created with Automator.  But now I realize that the only way I know how to stop the meteor server is to do a CTL-C in the terminal window.  But if start the meteor server with my script, I don't have a shell window.  Is there a way to stop the server through a shell script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can kill meteor with this command, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238382/how-to-stop-meteor):

```
kill $(ps ax | grep '[m]eteor' | awk '{print $1}')
```

Comment: Sure enough, that works!  Interestingly, I get no error when I run it from the terminal window, but I get an error when I run it from the shell script.  The error is identified as '(9)'. ???  But, it works either way.  Thanks very much.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's happening, but make sure that you're running it in the same shell by adding a shebang to the top of your shell script: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: `kill -9` should be used as a last resort as it doesn't let the target process clean up.  Prefer: `kill \`ps ax | grep [m]eteor | awk '{print $1}'\``

Comment: @alanning It might have just been your flavor of *nix, but I needed to encapsulate `[m]eteor` in quotes to get it to work. Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: Interesting. I just do a `sudo killall -9 node` why would you not use this? Am I overlooking some side effect to killall node?

Comment: I'm assuming that not letting the target clean up could result in a memory leak, so I've switched to allaning's method.  I still get the error, but it does work.  (I also still get the error with the shebang added.)  Also, I had to quote [m]eteor like christianbundy.

Comment: These answers go into more depth on why `kill -9` shouldn't be the first thing attempted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process
There are people who feel everything _should_ be able to recover cleanly (and I believe meteor does) but its still nice to let the process you are killing at least log that it is being terminated by the user rather than some unexpected error.

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy, meteor may not be the only node process running